# Regarding Retrieve AWS EC2 Instance as a snapshot

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

We had an instance where MongoDB hosted. now MongoDB someone deleted data by mistaken and we don't have any snapshots policy to retrieve backup for that account...

In this case, Can AWS provide backup as a snapshot from their data center backup mechanism??

Please let me know as its very important for us to work out this.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately if you do not see an EBS  snapshot in the account, then it does not exist. AWS does not keep extra backups of snapshots separate from it's customer accounts.

Under the AWS Shared Responsibility Model, customer data, including backups of that data, are the sole responsibility of the customer.

See https://aws.amazon.com/compliance/shared-responsibility-model/